# IntelliJ IDEA Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, code-generation, intellij-idea

I'm learning hibernate and I am running into some issues. I'm reading "Harnessing Hibernate" by O'Reilly. They explain everything using ANT, but since I want to avoid writing a huge build.xml file, I'm trying to get it to work with IntelliJ.

I managed to make a mapping according to a DB table in a MySQL database, and wrote the bean for it. It worked, but I can't find any information on how to generate beans and SQL code, or how to reverse engineer with IntelliJ. I found loads of tutorials about Eclipse, using JBOSS Hibernate tools plugin, and the site claims this support for generating code is already in the standard installation of IntelliJ.

Am I forgetting some configuration such as adding libraries? I'm trying to find this out but I'm desperate now. Please don't suggest me to use Eclipse, I need IntelliJ for my current role.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

AFAIK, IntelliJ IDEA includes the complete JPA/Hibernate support in its Ultimate Edition:

> #### [Generating Persistence Mappings from Database Schema](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/#link5)
>
> IntelliJ IDEA allows you to quickly
>   generate persistence mappings from any
>   database schema: Generating
>   Persistance Mappings
>
> [image]
>   <sub>(source: [jetbrains.com](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/screenshots/90/gen_pers_map.png))</sub>

Now, the question is, what edition of Intellij IDEA are you using?

Comment: I found that screenshot as well on jetbrains website but can't seem to find this. It only allows me to generate from database schema, not by mappings.

help--> about says: intelliJ IDEA ULTIMATE 9.0 (I have a school license)

Comment: @toomuchcs if you have a school license you should just download the latest version 15.0, its free for students

Answer (score 0):

If you add the `hbm2ddl` to your Hibernate config and ask it to create the database schema you'll get it by running a single test or some other code that exercises Hibernate.  Once you have it, turn off create.

Let Hibernate do the work.

Comment: thanks, that's already one step further, though I'm still not right on track. I added the property you said to my hibernate.cfg.xml, but now it complains it can't find the bean corresponding to the mapping file.
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: class com.hb.Track not found while looking for property: id

this is my cfg: http://pastebin.com/NrjFWE5p